# How to output wp_list_categories with extra markup

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm currently using the below script to output all my wordpress categories in an unordered list. How can I have the output with extra markup?

```
<ul><?php wp_list_categories('title_li&show_count=1');?></ul>
```

For example:

```
<ul>
<li>Category 1 &rsaquo;</li> 
<li>Category 2 &rsaquo;</li> 
</ul>
```

Instead of

```
<ul>
<li>Category 1</li> 
<li>Category 2</li> 
</ul>
```

Edit: Changed it to the following with the help of Obmerk Kronen:

```
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'number' => 20, // how many categories
  );
$categories = get_categories($args);
  foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a>&rsaquo;</li>';
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways you can easily do it .

1 - Use [get_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)

```
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'number' => 20 // how many categories
  );
$categories = get_categories($args);
  foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a></li>&rsaquo;';
    }
```

2 - use the css [`:after` selector](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after/) with the same code as you have posted in your question

```
.my_class li:after{ content:" \203A";}
```

See other characters and how to use them [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/glyphs/)

Comment: Thank you sir!
You have however forgotten a comma next to the order array.
Also the > asci symbol is placed on the next horizontal line instead of next to the category name. I've corrected these 2 things, please see my question edit. Do you know how I can have the category count next to each category? If you could edit your answer, then I can mark it as accept. Merry Xmas

Comment: correction: > asci symbol on next horizontal line was correct at your solution, I've asked it wrong. I've changed it at my question

Comment: Dude .. In my answer you have a [LINK](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) . have you tried to read it ?? Voting down for this is a bit ridiculous . You just have to read the link of the codex [HINT](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories#Return_values) .