# How to output categories with custom markup and hierarchy?

Tags: php, wordpress

[On this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775747/how-to-output-wp-list-categories-with-extra-markup) I have found the following

```
$args = array(
 'orderby' => 'name',
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'number' => 20 // how many categories
);
$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) { 
  echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a></li>&rsaquo;';
}
```

That's a step but that it isn't creating a hierarchy. I have read [get categories in wp codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) but I couldn't work it out.

My structure is:

```
CAT 1
  cat 1.1
  cat 1.2
CAT 2
  cat 2.1
  cat 2.2
```

Tried this but the output is simply a list of items with no hierarchy at all:

```
public function walk_taxonomy( $type = "checkbox", $args = array() ) {
    $args['walker'] = new Search_Filter_Taxonomy_Walker($type, $args['name']);
    $output = $argo = array(
        'hierarchical' => 1
        );
        $categories = get_categories($argo);
        foreach($categories as $category) { 
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a></li>&rsaquo;';
        } 
    if ( $output )
        return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add this to the args:

```
'hierarchical' => 1,
```

in your foreach you have to check if $category->parent is empty or not.. if not empty indent by adding spaces or applying a class to your li like

```
<li class="indent">
```

Comment: even by adding that the output it is not with hierarchy

Comment: so why don't you use: wp_list_categories() ?

Comment: you can.. there the walker option in the args